# Is this a reasonable financial plan? - Spend all of your money every few years?

Tags: savings, retirement, retirement-plan, travel, early-retirement

Ok, the title is intentionally a bit facetious. But a bit about my current situation.

I live in Europe (a high cost of living country) and save around 10,000 Euros per year. I have been doing this for 2 years, so have around 20,000 in cash, but I also have just over 10k in equity in my house.

I have always disliked the 9 - 5 lifestyle, but do not have the mentality to become an entrepreneur. At the same time, I don't want a 'deferred life' plan, of building up a pension and waiting until I'm 70 to live what's left of my life.

***So, I would like to ask if the below is a viable plan, if anyone else is doing something similar and if there are any obvious massive pitfalls?***

- Work for 2 - 3 years at a time, save up 20 - 30k.
- Take 2 - 3 years off work, travel the world on a budget, stay in hostels, live frugally, learn new skills and just generally enjoy life, (all the while not working and spending most of the savings).
- Repeat steps 1 and 2 until graveyard time.

**Pros** that I can see:

- No 'deferred life', live 2 - 3 year bursts of retirement while still young (I am 30).
- A couple of years off work should not be enough to deter employers, when it comes time to look for employment again (I am a software dev).

**Cons:**

- No long-term savings or investments

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to read the book called A Four Hour Work Week.

Comment: @PeteB. I've read the summary. It's aimed at people wanting to make their own business though, which I don't.

Comment: "travel the world on a budget, stay in hostels, live frugally" - so, having a live WAAAAAY worse than the 9-5 lifestyle? And ruining your resume and loosing your job on the way? Any logic in that? I do NOT see deferred life here - I see self destruction and a WAY lower life to start with.

Comment: @TomTom That's entirely subjective and your opinion. To some (such as myself) living a frugal life that means getting to see the world is WAY better than stuck in the 9-5 rat race for years on end.

Comment: But to THAT level? That means never finding a woman, never raising a child. This is not a life plan. Even with no plan to have children NOW - what if you change your mind? And getting back in a job like that means ALWAYS being a Junior. This sounds a TON like no plan as in "not planned and not spent a night about possibly things happening in the next years".

Comment: You are probably underestimating the consequences onto finding a new job. Chances are that you will be unemployed and without income for extended times. No company wants to hire someone after being out of touch for years with industry developments, who also probably leaves again after two years.

Comment: @TomTom: I know lots of employers that would find a 3-years abroad on Budget trip much much more interesting in a resume then the 1000th school-university-worko-work-work resume!

Comment: Also VTC, because the answer entirely depends on you personal taste!

Comment: @TomTom: You gather incredible soft-skills and chances are you come back and get entirely new job-opportunities unavailable to the "normal" employee. Also, there are employers that would even take you back after your time off if you did a good job before and stay transparent about your goals ...

Comment: Yeah, except the OP does not say he wants a different job. Soft skills are not important if you CAN NOT DELIVER. And IT people rather need to stay current on the software they work on. Want to know how many versions of PHP, C#, dotnet were published in the last 2 years?

Comment: @Daniel Some employers will not be impressed by their CV due to the short stays in any one job and long gaps where skills aren't being used and kept up-to-date. Some employers won't be put off, or may even view it as a positive, but overall they're probably decreasing their chances of finding a job. Spending *all* of their savings before they return to work isn't a reasonable plan unless they're okay with a high amount of risk. They need to be realistic about how long it will take them to find a job, and ensure they have enough left to cover **more than** that period.

Comment: It definitely does *not* seem a viable plan [while you're working to obtain your private pilot's license](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/56325/753), given the costs involved in doing so.

Comment: @TomTom: That is nonsense. If you where good in PHP two years ago you need one week tops to get up to speed again. Chances are your Employer didnt´t even update to the latest version yet. Heck, there are Banks still paying people to program in Cobol!

Comment: Yes, on YOUR level maybe. But senior jobs - nope.

Comment: @αCVn I have a separate fund for that

Comment: Outside of the questions of personal taste (I don't find travel all that much fun, myself), one important thing to consider is that life becomes SO much less complicated when you've accumulated a sizeable amount of money.  (Whether you think of it as a "retirement fund" or just as a safety net is up to you.)  It's much easier to take a year or two off, or take more interesting but less remunerative jobs, if you have a few hundred thousand in the bank, and will still have most of it when you go back to working.

Comment: Why not instead work hard, earn as much as you can and invest as much as you can, become financially free, then retire early and go see the world in style. Or alternatively get employment overseas in your field, travel rhat part of the world whilst working there, then go work in another part of the world and so on.

Comment: Come to the US for low taxes.  I am only in a 28% tax bracket. Really.  Well plus 11.2% for state, but that's all.  Well wait,13.4% for both sides of FICA, 8% VAT on any purchases, have to pay my own healthcare but that's only $700/mo. Also pay my own college, but primary school is free.  I am so lucky to be here where taxes are cheap and not one of those expensive European countries!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Some employers actually support a lifestyle similar to this in form of allowing "[sabbaticals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbatical)". It usually works like this:

1. Over a course of a few years, you either work extra hours or take a paycut.
2. Then you can take an extended period of paid leave, equivalent to the unpaid hours you've worked during those years (usually up to one year).
3. During that paid leave you do whatever you want.
4. When the paid leave is over, you can return to your previous position (or resign if you found something better to do... but don't tell your boss that I said that :))

The ratio between work years and free years is usually around 4:1, not 1:1 as in your plan. But the advantage of using such a sabbatical system over your proposed course of action is:

- You still receive your salary during your career break, so you don't need to worry about running out of money prematurely.
- You still enjoy all the employment benefits, like health insurance for example.
- You don't need to find a new job after your career break.
- You don't end up with gaps in your employment history which would otherwise make you look less employable
- You still accumulate retirement benefits and can retire as usual.

So if there is enough demand for people with your qualifications that you can choose between different employers, try to find one which offers this opportunity. But remember to read the fine-print. Some companies have very broad non-compete clauses in their contracts which do not get suspended while you are on sabbatical. This can greatly limit what you can do during them.

Comment: This seems by far the most realistic way to achieve what OP is after (if OP is able to find a company that supports this).

Answer (score 32):

I can see several problems with your plan:

- Retirement exists for a reason. There are various things that may prevent you from working when you are older:

  - You may be less able to work, be it because of physical deterioration of your body or mental exhaustion. And that's just the normal process - if you are unlucky, you might become sick and completely unemployable.
  - You are "less valuable" to many employers (at least in their eyes), when you are older. So they might not hire you. Then what?
- People might not hire you when they see your CV, extrapolating that you are going to quit after 2-3 years. It's not the "time off" (that you mention) that deters employers, it's the permanent quitting.

If you are really able to save 1 year's worth of expenses in 1 year of work, just work 2 decades and retire then, with compounding working for you (which it doesn't, if you spend all your savings every couple of years), you may then retire *for good*.

Or try to find a job/work/occupation that gives you the freedom/adventure/satisfaction you need.

Answer (score 11):

The very big risk I can see is that you don't plan to retire, ever:

> Repeat steps 1 and 2 until graveyard time.

While that might sound feasible now, at a still fairly young age, can you honestly, really say that you'll still be willing (and even able) to work when you're 70? 80? 90?

Comment: This isn't really an answer. Yes - software development is not strenuous physically.

Comment: @Cloud I'm aware of that (I'm a developer myself). Have you considered the mental aspects of the job though - I'm pretty sure something like Alzheimer's or similar would leave me unable to work even if I was physically fine.

Comment: When you're young, you think that  you'll still be as effective and as efficient in 30-40 years (eg. non strenuous software development) but even if not afflicted with dementia, the mind slows up as the decades add up.

Comment: I am also working in software development and I can confirm the points of Tom Revell and Bob Baerker. Our development department has an unusually large age span ranging from people in their 20s to people in their 60s and every age group in between. You can tell that the older people get the harder it gets for them to grasp new technologies and methodologies. Their experience alone is not enough to allow them to keep up with the younger generation. When developers go towards retirement, they notice that they are getting too old for this industry.

Comment: Yes this is an answer.  In addition to mental health issues, being able to work can include being able to be hired.  And an older person with a work history of 2-3 years at a time wont look good.

Comment: @Philipp: Speaking from experience, it's not that most older people have a hard time grasping new technologies, it's that we often fail to see the point of investing time & effort to adopt the latest fad when we've seen so many come and go without providing any measurable benefit.  Show us something that's actually a significant improvement, though...

Comment: Also, fads are happening all the time, and quite a few are built on top of other fads. It may be harder to understand some concepts, especially ones built atop others (Angular on top of JS on top of Node on top of Docker on top of IaaS) and considering all that when you're trying to 'catch up' with the times can be overwhelming. But we could say the same reversed (myself trying to understand mainframe programming).

Answer (score 7):

**You are missing out on a huge chunk of compound interest**

Long-term investments enjoy the magic of compound interest, which requires that growth in savings stays invested so it can grow even more. Imagine a situation where you are able to save $1,000 every month. If you save for 3 years at 6.5% interest, you will have nearly $40k before you quit working and start to spend your nest egg, before doing it all over. Repeating this 10 times earns you around $400k total.

Now suppose you save $1,000 every month at 6.5% interest, and do so for 30 years straight. By the end of your working career, you will have $1.1 million, nearly 3 times the amount as if you had saved and spent in bursts.

These numbers  don't even take into account how long it will take to spend the whole nest egg, during which time you're also accruing interest. The long term investment has the advantage there as well.

**Long-term investment averages may not apply**

My example uses a 6.5% interest rate, which is a reasonable long-term average return in the stock market. When saving in the long term, it's possible to ride out years of poor performance, because you have decades for short-term losses to be covered by long-term gains. If you always invest your money and actually need it 3 years later, the stock market becomes a riskier bet. If you happen to have a downturn as you finish a working stint, you might be in trouble. Long-term retirement savings plans tend to transition investments from high-risk, high-reward stocks to more stable, but lower return investments as retirement age nears. There's simply no time to do that when investing and withdrawing in cycles of 3 years.

Comment: The problem is that with the current zero interest rate in the Eurozone and the non-zero inflation, it is difficult to find a secure investment which results in a net gain of purchasing power. 6.5% guaranteed interest is completely unrealistic in Europe right now.

Comment: @Philipp Exactly this. I'm lucky to get 1.5%

Comment: @Philipp Except that he's not talking a savings account. Get into stocks and bonds. You will lose some money in the short term, but overall in the long term you have a **much** higher probability of making money.

Comment: @Philipp If you're putting retirement savings into a vanilla savings account, you're doing it wrong. You're absolutely correct, you won't outpace inflation by much, if at all. Long-term investments that can mitigate risk over time are key. You don't need 6.5% *guaranteed* interest, you need 6.5% *average* interest, which is a huge difference.

Comment: "The problem is that with the current zero interest rate in the Eurozone and the non-zero inflation" - yeah. My conservative investments did around 15% in the last year. Some searching required. Going to banks is "why do others not pay me for using their brain" level. My risk investments where WAY higher. So yes, this answer is valid.

Answer (score 5):

No, generally your plan as stated is not reasonable. Unforeseen emergencies mean you are running the risk of finding yourself in a financial black hole by spending your money every few years. What happens if you get injured while travelling in a way that means you can't work and your savings run out getting you back home? You also miss out on the benefits of compound interest - you are obliterating the potential long term returns on your pension by taking year-long gaps every now and again.

However, as a software developer you have the opportunity of having the best of both worlds by working freelance. Many developers choose to travel and work while overseas because all you really need is a laptop and an internet connection to do your work. Being freelance also means you can choose when you work and for how long at a time, so you could for example work for 2 weeks then take 2 weeks off etc. This way you still have things to put on your CV and you still generate an income, but you're working on your own schedule and can work while also travelling the world.